# AWS EC2DBサーバー（Oracle)にMS ACCESSからODBC接続する方法

Tags: amazon-ec2, oracle, ms-access, odbc

お世話になります。標題につきまして、MS ACCESSをフロントエンドにしてバックエンドの
AWS EC2(Oracle12c)へ接続することは可能でしょうか？
類似質問でMYSQLサーバーに接続する質問と回答はありましたが、Oracleへの接続方法の質問と回答が
なかったため、質問させて頂きました。
どなたかご存じの方いらっしゃいましたらご教示頂ければ幸いです。

Comment: どの部分がわからないのかが質問文から読み取れませんでした。例えばEC2でない場合の接続方法は把握できていますでしょうか？ そうでなくEC2に関係なく接続方法が知りたいのであれば、質問文からEC2を消した方が的確な答えが得られると思います。

Comment: 現在質問者さん本人と思われる方から編集提案がされていますが、本来質問者自身であれば質問は自由に編集できます。もしアカウン‌​‌​‌​トが2つに分かれてしまった場合は‌​、[ア‌​カウ‌​ントのマージ](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts)を行ってくだ‌​さい。